# Removing the black bar on top and bottom of html5 videos in Chrome and Safari browsers

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am using html5 video. In FireFox it is running well but in chrome and safari, it is showing a thick black bar top and bottom. How to get rid of this bars?

the code,

```
<video autoplay loop="loop" onended="this.play()" width="100%">
     <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
     <source src="videos/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try setting the height and width of the `video` element to the actual video and height of the video?

Comment: Thanks for reply,but I want video to take 100% width of the browser.

Comment: Then modify the height to adjust appropriately to scale to the width of the browser window.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at the dimensions and/or CSS of the tag containing your video tag. That will probably be a div. I had one with height:100%. Once i removed it, it solved the problem.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

For me, it was `line-height`. Setting `line-height: 0` on the parent element of  fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are the blackbars already in the actual video?? My solution is to play the video in a 16/9 iframepage and adjust top (..-px), left (..-px), height (..%) (OR width %) untill they are overscaled in an external .fullscreen-bg .css

Comment: .fullscreen-bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
    position: absolute;
    top:-10px;
    left: -220px;
    width: 142%;
    height: ;
    
}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by setting css style for video tag:

```
outline: none;
```