# HTML5 <video> width and height

Tags: html, video

I'm working to get a video on my webpage with the `video` tag.

I'm using FlareVideo to create my video tag. I can get the video to work on every browser that I need (IE 7/8/9, Firefox, Chrome, Safari).

The thing is, when I set the width and heigt, it looks like Safari and Chrome do not care at all and just put the right width, but a way too high height.

Also, with IE 7 and 8, the flash player used when HTML5 video is not supported by the browser is too small.

Hope somebody can help
Thanks

EDIT: added code

The HTML code

```
<div id="flarevideo" class="video-player" style="display:none;"></div>
```

The javascript code

```
function vidSwap(vidURL, awidth, aheight) {
    var pwidth = 720;
    var pheight = 406;
    $("div.video-player").show();
    fv = $("#flarevideo").flareVideo({
        flashSrc: window.pathToFlashVideo,
        width: pwidth,
        height: pheight,
        autobuffer: false,
        preload: false
    });
    fv.load([
        {
            src: '[server address]' + vidURL +'.mp4',
            type: 'video/mp4'
        },
        {
            src: '{server address]' + vidURL + '.ogv',
            type: 'video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'
        }
    ]); 
}
```

Note that the javascript is a bit different that what it should be (width and heigth here are hardcoded instead of using the two parameters of my function). 
Also, the format of vidUrl is "/[name fo the video without extension"]
And, window.pathToFlashVideo is the path for the flash fallback, defined on my html page

Comment: What size is your video, and what size are you trying to set it to?

Comment: The size of my video is 720X406 px, and i'm trying to set it to exaclty that.

See post for html/js

Comment: While doing some research i also found this guy who has the same problem as me 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128334/black-bar-on-top-and-bottom-of-html5-videos-in-chrome-and-safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem was coming from the div's CSS that contained the video. I removed the height:100% and now it's working fine.

Hope this helps anybody else with the same problem

Comment: Good advice - especially worth remembering if you use twitter bootstrap or other frameworks (all the more reason not to use them, imo...)